# Clean code and Nested promises

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, ecmascript-6, es6-promise

What's the right strategy to using nested promises to write clean code? One of the ideas behind using promises is to get rid of nested callbacks aka `callback hell`. Even when using promises, nesting seems to be unavoidable sometimes:

```
User.find({hande: 'maxpane'})
  .then((user) => {
    Video.find({handle: user.handle})
     .then((videos) => {
       Comment.find({videoId: videos[0].id})
        .then((commentThead) => {
            //do some processing with commentThread, vidoes and user
        })
     })
  })
```

Is there a way to get rid of the nesting and make the code more "linear". As it is, this code doesn't look very different from code that uses callbacks.

Comment: Seems like [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28250680/how-do-i-access-previous-promise-results-in-a-then-chain) could be a good read for you, if not a duplicate.

Answer (score 4):

The biggest advantage of using promises is chaining. That is how you should use it properly:

```
User.find({handle: 'maxpane'})
.then((user) => {
  return Video.find({handle: user.handle})
})
.then((videos) => {
  return Comment.find({videoId: videos[0].id})
})
.then((commentThead) => {
  //do some processing with commentThread, vidoes and user
})
```

Every time you return a Promise inside of `.then` it is used as a Promise for the next `.then` callback.

Comment: Are `commentThread`, `videos` and `user` variables available in the final function, It appears to me that only commentThread is within the scope of the function.